# How do I add OnClick event on part of the text?

Tags: onclick, inno-setup

I need to add **OnClick** event to part of the text in installer.

So it will be like this "bla bla bla **clickable text** bla bla bla".

Also this text should be with WordWrap property set to True, since I don't know exact size of it because of bunch of localizations.

I was trying to split text into 3 parts so it will be like this

"*Not-clickable*-text1 **clickable-text2** *Not-clickable*-text3"

but the problem begins when text3 should go to the next line of installer. It starts from position of **text3.Left** property, but I need it to start on next line from **text1.Left** property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing like click-able part of the text in Inno.

You really need to use 3 "texts"- either TLabel or TNewStaticText - to build the whole sentence. The middle one will have set Font property to bold, underline or blue color (depends you want the link) and Cursor set to Hand, ... and of course the OnClick event.

Both components have property AutoSize and WordWrap which you can use.

**AutoSize** property set to true makes your component to fit width and height to text size. Set it to True for all 3 texts.

Position texts like this:

```
Text1.Left := 10; // 10 is just example
Text1.Top := 10; // 10 is just example 
Text2.Left := Text1.Left + Text1.Width + 3; // 3 is space
if(Text1.Height > $Constant$) then
  Text3.Top := Text1.Top + Text1.Height + 3 // Create new line
else
  Text3.Left := Text2.Left + Text2.Width + 3;
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` functions when setting control positions via numeric constants.

Comment: In that case if text3 cannot fit first line, it ALL will move  to the new line. But I need it to be a part of text1 and text2 so it will fill the first line as much as possible and the rest will go to the new line

Comment: Such functionality is really complicated. I assume it can be achieved by using 4 texts where third one will contain so much character which can be added to fill the current line and text4 will move to next line. Use for loop to get character from text and it it fits the line then append it to text3 else stop and create text4 (new line). There are some methods how to measure the text but I am not able to write this code from my head.